# React-Native fetch records with token

Tags: react-native, jwt, fetch, saga

I tried to the following *saga* codes in my RN app but server responses with "No token is present" (Status 400 - Bad request). So the question is which is the bad part?

I use console.log to get the response which suppose to display list of vehicles.

The "CORS" mode at the server is enabled.

FYI, I managed to login with email/password to the same server and get the token using similar (saga) codes.

Any clues why the codes below do not work?

```
function* fetchVehicles(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield fetch(URL_VEHICLES, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${action.token}`,
      },
    });
    yield console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Saga error: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot ( no copy paste ) of what's inside your action ?